# Angular/Rails $resource params on the server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

There is the following code:

```
  $scope.event = new Event({ start_time: new Date(), animator_ids: [0] })
  $scope.event.start_time.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)

  $scope.createEvent = ->
    $scope.event.animator_ids = [1, 2, 3]
    $scope.buttonText = "Saving..."
    $scope.event.$save ->
      $state.go('events.all')
```

And Rails server code:

```
  def create
    render json: params and return
  end
```

JSON respond:

```
{"start_time":"2015-01-07T21:00:00.000Z","animator_ids":[1,2,3],"title":"1","description":"2","format":"json","action":"create","controller":"events","event":{"title":"1","description":"2","start_time":"2015-01-07T21:00:00.000Z"}}
```

I don't understand why 'start_time' in 'event' group, but 'animator_ids' is not!! I need to move 'animator_ids' to the same group, how can I do it? Thanks!